# Android conversion from Calendar to ISO 8601

Tags: android, date, datetime, calendar, iso8601

I need a conversion from Calendar (from class import java.util.Calendar)  to standard ISO 8601 data time, that is:

```
     YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with your required format string.